# How to use python listdir in org babel?

Tags: org-babel, python

While the command below returns filenames in the commandline, I somehow can't get the same result using org-babel:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output
import os
os.listdir(path='.')
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
None
```

Altering the command e.g. using `scandir` nor the `:results` property (value,raw) helped

Comment: You might want to print the return value of that function so babel can pick it up and show it as results of evaluation.

Answer (score 2):

By using `:results value` and returning a value, the result will be a list:

```
#+begin_src python :results value
import os
return os.listdir(path='.')
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
| python.org | foo.txt | bar.txt |
```

Returning the results as an org table, as above, makes the results easy to use as the input to other `src` blocks. But, if you want the result to be formatted like a python list, you can use `:results value pp`:

```
#+begin_src python :results value pp
import os
return os.listdir(path='.')
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: ['python.org', 'foo.txt', 'bar.txt']
```

or `:results output` and print the result:

```
#+begin_src python :results output
import os
print(os.listdir(path='.'))
#+end_src

#+RESULTS:
: ['python.org', 'foo.txt', 'bar.txt']
```